# "I can grant that easily" vs "That I may grant easily"

Tags: word-usage, word-order

I found a phrase

"That I may grant easily."

in a Dragon Ball comic book.  Sheng-Long, the divine dragon with the power to grant people's wish, says this.

Is this the same as "I can grant that easily"?

Is it old-fashioned English?

Answer (score -1):

Either one can be used in both contexts. It just depends on which one sounds better.

"I can grant you powers easily."

"I have powers that I may grant easily."